# How would I go about making an ionic timer the client can change themselves?

Tags: angularjs, timer, ionic-framework, client

I'm thinking if I clicked the center, I would change the timer in the middle with whatever minutes or seconds I want. How could I do that rather than a hardcoded 1 minute timer?

http://codepen.io/comapedrosa/pen/ONYgzJ

```
 // When you press a timer button this function is called
$scope.selectTimer = function() {
  $scope.timeForTimer = 60;
  $scope.timer = 60;
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a little example for you which you can implement the way you want. Basically it's just a few things that needed to be changed/fiddled around with.

In this example I made a simple input where you could set the time (in seconds). The input can be found on the top left of the header and it looks like this:

```
<input class="time" type="number" ng-model="timerTime" placeholder="Set time" ng-change="selectTimer()"/>
```

The class is just for making it look a little nicer and stand out from the background but all you really need is the `ng-model` and `ng-change`. The `ng-model` is the model that is updated on the scope for the timer to use it as the value and the `ng-change` function is there to "reload" the timer when the `ng-model` is changed.

In the controller I set the initial value for the timer with:

```
$scope.timerTime = 60;
```

Then you need to assign this value to the correct function at:

```
$scope.selectTimer = function() {
  $scope.timeForTimer = $scope.timerTime;
  $scope.timer = $scope.timerTime;
};
```

And finally on the `ng-change` we are calling the `$scope.selectTimer` which will then update the timer itself with the value inserted in the input.

You could then disable the input when the timer is running/is not reset so that it won't mess up the process. This should probably be done even if it's a pop-up or whatever you are going to implement the final setting of the time.

But as I said I'm not sure how you would like to implement this so I made this example simple as this. Please use it as needed and wanted.

Codepen demo can be found here: http://codepen.io/thepio/pen/PzyPxk